# How can I know when a window popup is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sLGLT/1/) my code:

```
var w = window.open("http://www.jsfiddle.net");

if (w) {
    w.onload = function() {
        $('#complete').html("finished");
    };
}
```

but I'm far away from by target. I want to write "finished" in the div when the window is loaded. How can I do it?

Comment: It is impossible when it is in another domain.

Comment: Ok. Suppose I'm in the same domain! (question edited)

Comment: unless it is the same domain i dont think you can get a finished callback as i think that would fall under cross domain sandbox, if it is on the same domain you can have the page that is being loaded execute a function of the window that opened it by using `window.parent.someGlobalFunctionInParent();` in an onload event

Comment: Did you not search the forum? asked a bunch of times.

Comment: if you were in the same domain, you could call `window.parent.frameHasLoaded();` you would need to create a function `frameHasLoaded` from where the popup was opened

Comment: oh, @PatrickEvans beat me...

Comment: For some reason I want to manage it from parent, not from the child. I'm in the same domain!

Comment: @markzzz it cannot be done, the event has to be fired from the child, and the parent is the listener

Comment: And can I know when a user close that popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to control from parent you could use ajax to grab the html and inject it into the popup window.

```
$.ajax({
   url:"somepage.html",
   success:function(html) {
     $('#complete').html("finished");
     var popup = window.open("");
     var doc = popup.document;
     doc.write(html);
   }
});
```

Though if the child page has scripts that depend on onload they may not fire,

Comment: Uhm no I cannot do this, because the page itself have some redirect that can require user input data.

Comment: And can I know when a user close that popup?

Comment: not sure if there is a callback for close, you might need again a function call in the popup, but from the parent you can check `popup.window` `popup.top` or others are `null` as they will become `null` when it is closed

Comment: as for the user input data, can you not just send the user inputs in the `data` option of the ajax call?

Comment: Long story about why I cannot ;) Uhm, `w.top` return to me the address? Sure this function exist?