# JS window.open(url) - how to get content of that page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window, window.open

I have file download in my app.
To download file in desktop I'm using iframe (to avoid page reload), but for mobile browsers I'm using window.open to download that file in new browser tab.

```
var newWindow = window.open(url);
$(newWindow.document.body).ready(function() {
    // ...
});
```

But in case of server error, backend is sending me error response to that window, so I need to read content of that window.

How to get content of that page in newWindow object in JS or jQuery? I need to read content of that page go handle server error in UI.

I tried

```
$(newWindow)[0].contents()
$(newWindow.document.body).contents()
$(newWindow.document.body).contents().find('body').text()
```

But it's not working :/

Comment: Why are you not just fetching the content with the XMLHttpRequest Object?

Comment: But how to get XHR object of that page in new window?

Comment: LIke this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916774/how-can-i-know-when-a-window-popup-is-loaded

Comment: right, but I need to do ajax call so that means I'll download that file to check XHR object, so user will wait long time for ajax success callback.

I found this solution:
`var newWindow = window.open(url);
$(newWindow).load(function() {
 var responseText = newWindow.document.documentElement.innerText || newWindow.document.documentElement.textContent;
});`